# cookies aren't enable - selenium webdriver.io phantomjs

Tags: selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, webdriver-io

Documentation says: Cookies are enabled in PhantomJS by default. But not sure why Amazon returns that page.

[image: saved screenshot of page]

Here is my code:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');

var opts = desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'phantomjs',
    javascriptEnabled: true
  },
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 4444
};

var email = ''; // your email
var password: ''; // your password

var client = webdriverio
      .remote(opts)
      .init()
      .url('https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/sign-in.html')
      .setValue('#ap_email', email)
      .setValue('#ap_password', password)
      .submitForm('form[name="signIn"]')
      .then(function() { // save the screenshot
              this.saveScreenshot(__dirname + '/loginPage.png');
      })
      .end();
```

I had logged the cookies object it returns empty/none:

```
{ 
  sessionId: 'a96eb340-bb6a-11e5-ae83-c52b2435a008',
  status: 0,
  value: [] 
}
```

, and tried to set a custom Cookie with

`.setCookie({name: '', value: '', domain: 'amazon.co.uk'})`

But still have the same problem..

As I think phantomJS is blocking it because when i changed the `browserName` with `chrome` then it works fine.. Still, I want it work via phantom.

Your help will be appreciated  - Thanks.

Comment: i wonder if amazon is checking the user-agent, and "assuming" your browser doesn't support cookies.  it may be prudent to try changing your user-agent header?

Comment: but phantomjs documentation says it supports cookies. version > 1.9.7! and i am using v2.0.0.. and i tried by changing user-agent header as well.        ``` userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.0.0 Safari/534.34" ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the website is not recognizing phantom as a normal browser and hence showing you this error message.

Add the User-Agent string in the browser capabilities as follows. This will tell the site that the traffic is coming from a normal browser.

```
var opts = desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'phantomjs',
   'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0 WebKit',
    javascriptEnabled: true
  },
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 4444
};
```

Comment: Okay, I will look into it when I get time, since this was asked ~3 months earlier. but sure i 'll look into and will mark it as soon as i verify it. this will definitely help others if they come to the issue here. thanks